# Android resource compilation failed 3

Tags: android, gradle

Below this, is my issue in my App when try to built it. I've tried lots of things but was unable to solve it.

**Android resource compilation failed**

> Output:  D:\ashish android\DreamTouchIndia\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2582: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/theme' with config ''.
>   D:\ashish android\DreamTouchIndia\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2582: error: resource previously defined here.

Command:

```
C:\Users\hp\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\3b90f5710266fb9a4db1b900d48eb915\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        D:\ashish android\DreamTouchIndia\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        D:\ashish android\DreamTouchIndia\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #2
```

Comment: show your styles.xml file

Comment: Put your gradle files.this error show in many case . if your project and library has same library use and defined in both gradle then remove library from gradle . if not solve then go to file invalidate cache / restart. change project gradle version upgrade.update from .property gradle version.. this all thing matters for this error

Answer (score 0):

check your module gradle . you may define dependency twice

Comment: This not an answer, most be a comment